# Can we upload files to hidrive online stroage from our rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, hidrive

In my rails application i have an option to upload documents. I want to save those uploaded documents somewhere in the online. I googled and got a free online storage site named hi drive (https://www.hidrive.strato.com/). Can we upload files to hidrive from our application using paperclip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can upload in many ways. Check following list for few of them

==> Using ftp upload
 [Check this gem for paper clip ftp upload](https://github.com/xing/paperclip-storage-ftp)

==> Using web-dav upload
[Check this gem for an idea](https://github.com/Nikita-V/paperclip-webdav)

==> Using direct api
[Hi Drive developer account](https://dev.strato.com/hidrive/)

[Check this to get good idea](http://community.free-hidrive.com/hidrive/topics/upload_files_to_hidrive_from_our_rails_application?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_reply&utm_content=reply_button&reply[id]=14641298#reply_14641298)

[Hidrive doc](http://www.strato-faq.co.uk/article/2046/What-are-the-paths-for-FTP,-SMB,-WebDav,-Rsync,-etc.-.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. 
There is a public API with wich you can use HiDrive from within your application. 
Check out: https://dev.strato.com/hidrive/